# Using Levi-civita symbol to determine axis and angle of rotation matrix

Tags: matrices, rotations

One of the questions on the course involves finding the angle and axis of this rotation matrix;

$$R = \gamma\
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -2 & 1\\ 
2 & 0 & 0\\ 
-1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

My lecturer solves this in an example that reads;

> $$
> \omega_i = -\frac{1}{2} \epsilon_{ijk}R_{jk}
> $$
>
> $$
> \omega_i = (R_{23},R_{31},R_{12})_i = \omega n_i
> $$
>
> Therefore the angle is $|\underline{\omega}| = \sqrt{5} \gamma$
>   and axis is $ \underline{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(0,1,2)$

Two questions;

1. What is $\omega$?
2. Is this method limited to this case or can it be applied generally?

Comment: Just wanted to note that I have now read more of the lectures notes and solutions (which can be found at http://www2.ph.ed.ac.uk/~rhorsley/) and it seems to be a genraly applicable method.